# UINavigationBar: buttons font color

Tags: iphone, button, fonts, colors, uinavigationbar

I have UINavigationBar and i've changed background color for all back buttons with

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationMyToolbar)
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.tintColor = <UIColor>;
}
```

But I couldn't find the answer how to change font color for all back buttons in app?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the button colors by changing the `navigationController.navigationBar` background color.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // or whatever color you like
```

Oh, if you want to change the entire app, place that in the AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and as long as you dont change it in any other controller, you should be good. If you have different colors for each view, then place that in the `viewWillAppear` or `init` for each view.

Comment: _font_ color not background color.

Comment: If you were to override the button and use a UILabel instead, then yes, otherwise no.